# Firebase iOS Swift Authentication API_UNAVAILABLE(macCatalyst) problem

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've just used identical procedures to those that were working a few weeks ago on an earlier app using Firebase Authentication in iOS/Swift. I've just added authentication code after configuring app, registering app, downloading & performing proper updates with the `GoogleService-Info.plist`, etc.

When I run, I get an error in `OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCustomBrowser.h` on the line:

```c
API_UNAVAILABLE(macCatalyst) // currently 38
```

stating it `"expected ;"`

Did a quick cross-ref of this Google code with code that worked & loaded via CocoaPods a few weeks ago, and there's no mention of `macCatalyst` in that code.

Any thoughts on what's up or suggested workarounds?

Answer (score 14):

I tried adding `pod 'AppAuth','~> 1.2.0'` and it at least compiled for me.  I'm going to do some more testing but as a "fix" for now this seems to work.

-Edit
Seems to be working fine now :) Hopefully they get the new version of AppAuth fixed, but it seems like 1.2.0 works well.

Comment: Adding Appauth 1.2.0 in podfile worked for me. Guess google might want ios devs to have latest build env...

Answer (score 6):

I was running under Xcode 10. Apparently everything works fine in Xcode 11. Perhaps Google's Firebase team didn't update w/backward compatibility in mind?

Answer (score 1):

Same issue with my app also. After some trial and error I found a solution.
Use pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 4.1.1' instead of version 5.0.1